# Exporting Apache HttpClient encryption keys to Wireshark

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a project where I have to interface with an undocumented webservice on HTTPS. I chose HttpClient for the job. I would like to see the actual exchange between my application and the server with packet capture. How can I extract encryption keys from Apache HttpClient? Chromium has a commandline option to export a master secret file that Wireshark can use to decode TLS, I'd like to do something similar with HttpClient.

Comment: See https://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL#Using_the_.28Pre.29-Master-Secret and possibly its reference to http://jsslkeylog.sourceforge.net/ . @Boris: you can decrypt non-FS (aka plain-RSA) suites using the server privatekey, but asker here can't even get doc on the server so they probably can't get privatekey; you can decrypt *any* suite using the per-session secret from either endpoint

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 interesting - I wasn't aware that there was a way to dump those without compiling a browser in development mode.